react-hook-form controller with auto update value on mount
I need to make it so that the value is set automatically when mounted. From outside the component I can't set it, because I have scripts when data retrieval requests happen in the component
The problem is that if I call onChange inside useEffect the component in render is not rendered because field.value is not changed, although field.onChange is triggered.
Is it possible to somehow set the value from inside the component in render method or it can't be done that way at all?
type TProps = {
  value: string;
  onChange?: (value: string) => void;
};
const TestInput = ({ onChange, value }: TProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    onChange?.('AutoSet');
  }, []);
  return <div>{value || 'empty'}</div>;
};

type Props = {
  name: string;
  control: Control<FieldValues>;
};
const TestInputController = ({ name, control }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      render={({ field, fieldState, formState }) => {
        return (
          <TestInput
            value={field.value}
            onChange={(value) => {
              field.onChange(value);
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
      name={name}
    />
  );
};


The issue you're encountering is due to the fact that the useEffect inside the TestInput component is causing an immediate onChange call which sets the value, but React Hook Form's Controller doesn't immediately recognize this change and thus doesn't update the field value in the render method of the Controller.
To address this issue, you can ensure that the value is properly propagated back to the Controller and trigger a re-render of the TestInput component. One approach is to use a local state in TestInput to handle the value and ensure the useEffect triggers an update to field.onChange.
Here are the example code:
const TestInput = ({ onChange, value }: TProps) => {
const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState(value)

useEffect(() => {
  setInternalValue('AutoSet')
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  onChange('AutoSet')
}, [internalValue])

  return <div>{value || 'empty'}</div>

}

